# Soft Question: Optimization

Tags: optimization, algorithms, numerical-optimization

Let $N$ be the number of locations for hotspots. Each has its cost and achievable rate. I want to find the optimal combinations of $n \leq N$ locations such the cost is minimized. How can I do so without computing all possible combinations?

Comment: What's your constraint? A total achievable rate is given as part of the problem?

Comment: Sounds like an instance of the Facility Location Problem (which can be solved using integer programming)